# azure .vhd image capture/load

Tags: azure, load, capture, vhd

I want to do the following:

1. In Azure, US East, capture current windows VM image (I know how to do that)
2. download .vhd image (I know how to do that)
3. Now, I want to load (that image I downloaded) in second(separate) Azure account in US West, how do I do that?

Can someone can help me out, thank you.

Comment: Off-Topic. SO is about programming questions, in a rather narrow sense. This question belongs to http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a storage in US West
2. Use Azcopy to copy the VHD image from US East Storage to US West Storage
3. Create a Virtual Machine using that copied VHD (may need to use powershell)

**Getting Started with the AzCopy Command-Line Utility**:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/

Comment: Hey Bruno, can you give me an actual command syntax? since in that AzCopy link there is way too much information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also important make sure you generalize your VM using sysprep otherwise your VM will not be accessible on restart.  Been down that road.  There are ways to get it back but not fun.  So pause before you click that "capture" button. If you do on restart it will fail due to "vm has been generalized". Generalization essentially removes all your personal information as well as other things...

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb457073.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/shwetanayak/2017/03/19/captured-the-virtual-machine-didnt-intend-to-generalize-it-now-what/